# Does the request for Location Updates from the location manager happen only after the minimum distance condition is met?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the Location manager to request for location updates with minimum battery consumption.
Now I use the following piece of code to request for Location Updates in my activity class.

**LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, polltimeInterval, minDistValue, locListener);**

Now i have set a Minimum Distance Value of 5 meters and a poll Interval of 1000 milliseconds. Now my question is does the request for location updates happen only if the minimum distance condition is met? or does it keep polling any way every 1 sec, but does not update the lat long , till the minimum distance condition is met.

Basically I am trying to understand how this particular method works with these two configurable parameters (poll Time and Mini mum distance)..is it either one of the two or both?...

Answer (score 0):

"The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life. "

Right from the documentation.  So both must be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i run the test and whenever the location changes, the onLocation Changed method gets invoked, i write the results to a file on the device. I see that it does not accurately wait for both conditions to be met. It keeps polling irrespective of the distance. What i  did basically to prove this is, i kept the device stationary and had the poll time as 30 sec, with min distance of 1 meter. Since the device has not moved, it should have recorded any changes, but it did which tells me that it does keep polling no matter what.

Comment: 1 meter is too low, its within the margin of error for GPS-  typical consumer GPS equipment has error and fluctuations of up to 10 meters.  Try with a higher threshold and see if its still reported.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that , when i chose GPS as provider, i do not receive location  updates if i set the min distance to 100 meters and  the polling as 30000 milliseconds, But if i chose the NETWORK as provider (WIFI using Google Location Service) i get only one update of location change. Does anyone know why this change in behavior between WI-FI and GPS?

Comment: Network is far less accurate.  It isn't even going to try to guess to the meter.  My guess is you moved less than the threshold for network to see a movement.

Comment: That might be true but i see that the onLocationChanged() method gets invoked in the location listener even though the device was stationary. Any idea why this happens with a NETWORK provider?

Comment: My only thought is maybe it thinks it changes whenever it sees signal strength variation.  Sounds like a bug, but I'm not crawling though the AOSP to find it